# Complex SQL query using grails,HQL

Tags: grails, hql, grails-orm

i am trying to write a 3 table join query in HQL grails my 3 classes are:

```
class Domains {
    String name
    Date ets
    Account account

    static hasMany = [facebooks: Facebook, twitters: Twitter]
}
```

...

```
class Facebook {
    Boolean activated
    String name
    String token
    String pageId
    String expiryTime
    String scope
    Date ets
    String username
    Domains domains

    static belongsTo = [Domains]
}
```

...

```
class FbPosts {
    String postId
    Long commentsCount
    Long likesCount
    Long sharesCount
    Date date
    Date ets
    String message
    String type
    Integer postImpression
    Facebook facebook

    static belongsTo = [Facebook]
}
```

i am trying to get `fbPosts` related to a domain (domain eid). my current HQL query looks like this:

```
def fbPosts = FbPosts.findAll("from FbPosts as fb join Facebook as f on f.eid=fb.facebook_eid join Domains as d on d.eid=f.domain_eid where d.eid=?"[domain_eid])
def map = [fbPosts:fbPosts]
```

and does not seem to work. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this then? The downside is that it will cause two separate database queries (unless the domains object already exist in the persistance cache).

```
def domainsInstance=Domains.get(domain_eid)
def fbPosts = FbPosts.withCriteria {
    facebook {
        eq('domains', domainsInstance)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work with a Criteria?

```
def fbPosts = FbPosts.withCriteria {
    facebook {
        domains {
            eq( 'eid', domain_eid )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @JJDev Also, where is `eid` coming from in `Domain`?  I can't see it in the domain object...

Comment: yup it is coming from Domain, the primary key for all tables are "eid", and  the foreign key for the respective tables are name_eid eg: facebook_eid,fbposts_eid,domains_eid.Dont ask why lol as i did not create the database

Comment: Should it be part of the domain class then?